Error when evaluating 'strategy' for job - GitHub Actions
I am trying to configure Key-Value Paris using GitHub Actions.
I have two workflows: Bulk-Config-KVM and Config-KVM.
Config-KVM can be used to configure only one set that has multiple KVMs per execution.
Bulk-Config-KVM is used for configuring multiple sets that has multiple KVMs.
Here is my input:
MapIdentifier11, Key11, Value11, Key12, Value12, Key13, Value13, Key14, Value14, true, MapIdentifier22, Key21, Value21, Key22, Value22, Key23, Value23, Key24, Value24, false, MapIdentifier33, Key31, Value31, Key32, Value32, Key33, Value33, Key34, Value34, false
I'm using Config-KVM as my re-useable workflow from Bulk-Config-KVM.
Config-KVM:
#Implementation of Config-KVM using GitHub Action
name: Config-KVM
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      MapIdentifier:
        type: string
        description: 'Provide  name of KVM'
      Key1:
        type: string
        description: 'Provide  Key1'
      Value1:
        type: string
        description: 'Provide  Value1'
      Key2:
        type: string
        description: 'Provide  Key2'
      Value2:
        type: string
        description: 'Provide  Value2'
      Key3:
        type: string
        description: 'Provide  Key3'
      Value3:
        type: string
        description: 'Provide  Value3'
      Key4:
        type: string
        description: 'Provide  Key4'
      Value4:
        type: string
        description: 'Provide  Value4'
      Encrypted:
        type: choice
        options:
          - true
          - false
  workflow_call:     
    inputs:
      MapIdentifier:
        type: string
        description: 'Provide  name of KVM'
      Key1:
        type: string
        description: 'Provide  Key1'
      Value1:
        type: string
        description: 'Provide  Value1'
      Key2:
        type: string
        description: 'Provide  Key2'
      Value2:
        type: string
        description: 'Provide  Value2'
      Key3:
        type: string
        description: 'Provide  Key3'
      Value3:
        type: string
        description: 'Provide  Value3'
      Key4:
        type: string
        description: 'Provide  Key4'
      Value4:
        type: string
        description: 'Provide  Value4'
      Encrypted:
        type: string
   
jobs:
  Create_Update-KVM:
    runs-on: [xxx]
    steps:
      - name: Execute cURL
        run: |
          echo "### Key4 = ${{ inputs.Key4 }} ###"
          if [ ${{ inputs.Key4 }} != "" ];
          then
            createresponse=`curl -k --write-out '%{http_code}' --header "authorization: Basic ${{ secrets.USER }}" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request POST --url 'https://example.com/keyvaluemaps' --data '{"encrypted": "${{ inputs.Encrypted }}","entry": [{"name": "${{ inputs.Key1 }}","value": "${{ inputs.Value1 }}"},{"name": "${{ inputs.Key2 }}","value": "${{ inputs.Value2 }}"},{"name": "${{ inputs.Key3 }}","value": "${{ inputs.Value3 }}"},{"name": "${{ inputs.Key4 }}","value": "${{ inputs.Value4 }}"}],"name": "${{ inputs.MapIdentifier }}"}'`
            
            if [[ $createresponse == *"201"* ]];
            then
              echo "KVM created successfully: $createresponse"
            else
              echo "Failed with $createresponse."
              exit 1
            fi

          elif [ ${{ inputs.Key3 }} != "" ];
          then
            createresponse=`curl -k --write-out '%{http_code}' --header "authorization: Basic ${{ secrets.USER }}" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request POST --url 'https://example.com/keyvaluemaps' --data '{"encrypted": "${{ inputs.Encrypted }}","entry": [{"name": "${{ inputs.Key1 }}","value": "${{ inputs.Value1 }}"},{"name": "${{ inputs.Key2 }}","value": "${{ inputs.Value2 }}"},{"name": "${{ inputs.Key3 }}","value": "${{ inputs.Value3 }}"}],"name": "${{ inputs.MapIdentifier }}"}'`
            
            if [[ $createresponse == *"201"* ]];
            then
              echo "KVM created successfully: $createresponse"
            else
              echo "Failed with $createresponse."
              exit 1
            fi

          elif [ ${{ inputs.Key2 }} != "" ];
          then
            createresponse=`curl -k --write-out '%{http_code}' --header "authorization: Basic ${{ secrets.USER }}" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request POST --url 'https://example.com/keyvaluemaps' --data '{"encrypted": "${{ inputs.Encrypted }}","entry": [{"name": "${{ inputs.Key1 }}","value": "${{ inputs.Value1 }}"},{"name": "${{ inputs.Key2 }}","value": "${{ inputs.Value2 }}"}],"name": "${{ inputs.MapIdentifier }}"}'`
            
            if [[ $createresponse == *"201"* ]];
            then
              echo "KVM created successfully: $createresponse"
            else
              echo "Failed with $createresponse"
              exit 1
            fi

          else
            createresponse=`curl -k --write-out '%{http_code}' --header "authorization: Basic ${{ secrets.USER }}" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request POST --url 'https://example.com/keyvaluemaps' --data '{"encrypted": "${{ inputs.Encrypted }}","entry": [{"name": "${{ inputs.Key1 }}","value": "${{ inputs.Value1 }}"}],"name": "${{ inputs.MapIdentifier }}"}'`
            echo "### createresponse = $createresponse ###"
            if [[ $createresponse == *"201"* ]];
            then
              echo "KVM created successfully."
            else
              echo "KVM already exists: $createresponse"
              exit 1
            fi
          fi

In the Bulk-Config-KVM, I'm using Matrix as my strategy:
name: Bulk-Config-KVM.yml

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      KVMs:
        type: string
        description: 'Provide the values in the following order MapIdentifier, Key1, Value1, Key2, Value2, Key3, Value3, Key4, Value4'

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: [xxx]
    outputs:
      iterations: ${{ steps.set-iterations.outputs.finalValues }}
    steps:
    - name: Start
      run: ls
    - name: Read JSON and trigger workflows
      id: set-iterations
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      run: |
        echo "Print Inputs provided by the user"
        echo "### KVMs = ${{ github.event.inputs.KVMs }} ###"

        echo "BEFORE"
        input="${{ github.event.inputs.KVMs }}"

        echo "### input = ${{ github.event.inputs.KVMs }} ###"
        echo "AFTER"

        # Convert input string to an array
        IFS=', ' read -r -a dataArray <<< "$input"

        # Initialize variables
        output="["
        index=0

        # Loop through the data array
        while [ $index -lt ${#dataArray[@]} ]; do
          # Create a map object
          map="{\"MapIdentifier\":\"${dataArray[$index]}\","
          index=$((index + 1))
          
          # Add key-value pairs
          for keyIndex in {1..4}; do
            key="Key$keyIndex"
            value="Value$keyIndex"
            map+="\"$key\":\"${dataArray[$index]}\", \"${value}\":\"${dataArray[$index + 1]}\", "
            index=$((index + 2))
          done

          # Add Encrypted field
          map+="\"Encrypted\":\"${dataArray[$index]}\"}"
          index=$((index + 1))

          # Add map to output
          output+="$map,"
        done

        # Remove the trailing comma and close the output JSON array
        output="${output%,}"
        output+="]"

        # Print the output
        echo "********"
        echo "$output"
        echo "********"
        echo "finalValues=$output" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

    - name: Check list
      run: |
        echo ${{ steps.set-iterations.outputs.finalValues }}

  call-Config-KVM:
    needs: [build]
    strategy:
      matrix: 
        iteration: ${{fromJson(needs.build.outputs.iterations)}}
    uses: ./.github/workflows/Config-KVM.yml
    secrets: inherit
    permissions:
      contents: read
    with: 
      MapIdentifier: ${{ matrix.iteration.MapIdentifier }}
      Key1: ${{ matrix.iteration.Key1 }}
      Value1: ${{ matrix.iteration.Value1 }}
      Key2: ${{ matrix.iteration.Key2 }}
      Value2: ${{ matrix.iteration.Value2 }}
      Key3: ${{ matrix.iteration.Key3 }}
      Value3: ${{ matrix.iteration.Value3 }}
      Key4: ${{ matrix.iteration.Key4 }}
      Value4: ${{ matrix.iteration.Value4 }}
      Encrypted: ${{ matrix.iteration.Encrypted }}
      
  check:
    needs: [build]
    runs-on: [xxx]
    strategy:
      matrix: 
        iteration: ${{fromJson(needs.build.outputs.iterations)}}
    steps:
      - name: Do something
        run: |
          echo Iteration
          echo ${{ matrix.iteration }}
          echo ${{ matrix.iteration.MapIdentifier }}
          echo ${{ matrix.iteration.Key1 }}
          echo ${{ matrix.iteration.Value1 }}
          echo ${{ matrix.iteration.Key2 }}
          echo ${{ matrix.iteration.Value2 }}
          echo ${{ matrix.iteration.Key3 }}
          echo ${{ matrix.iteration.Value3 }}
          echo ${{ matrix.iteration.Key4 }}
          echo ${{ matrix.iteration.Value4 }}
          echo ${{ matrix.iteration.Encrypted }}

Error: Error when evaluating 'strategy' for job 'check'. .github/workflows/Bulk-Config-KVM.yml (Line: 105, Col: 20): Error parsing fromJson,.github/workflows/Bulk-Config-KVM.yml (Line: 105, Col: 20): Error reading JToken from JsonReader. Path '', line 0, position 0.,.github/workflows/Bulk-Config-KVM.yml (Line: 105, Col: 20): Unexpected value ''
How to fix this and how to identify the right strategy for the different use cases?

for steps.set-iterations.outputs.values to work you need to actually generate the output for GH like this:
echo "values=$values" >> GITHUB_OUTPUT
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-output-parameter
